# Selenium WebDriver, when loading an HTTPS website, closes and reopens browser and does not even attempt to interact with the DOM

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, https, webdriver

Selenium WebDriver (run from Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)) seems to be unable to handle any HTTPS website.

By that I mean this: upon loading the page (regardless of whether it redirects or not, tried with gitlab and AWS logon sites)

- Logon page loads properly (no SSL certificate issues, any redirect happens just fine), yet Selenium doesn't do anything (debug mode shows it's not even trying to execute the logon code)
- It times out (browserWaitTimeout=15) and closes/reopens the logon page
- This happens until the 4th time, upon which Selenium finally reaches my logon code (a breakpoint I set there is finally hit), but this happens between browser page closing and reopening, thus it never detects the DOM and fails.

And the most frustrating thing is, console shows NO ERRORS.
Here: Chrome:

```
Jul 03, 2019 8:40:44 AM com.fincad.vcr.qa.support.WebDriverFactory createWebDriver

INFO: Web driver is created successfully

Jul 03, 2019 8:40:55 AM com.fincad.vcr.qa.support.WebDriverFactory quitWebDriver

INFO: Web driver quits successfully
```

That's it, as in literally it (notice the 15 second gap? That's browserWaitTimeout).

a) I tried FF, where I saw errors from Marionette:

```
1562172157538   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56792

1562172157572   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database

1562172157603   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering upgrade listener for 
formautofill@mozilla.org

Jul 03, 2019 9:42:37 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Jul 03, 2019 9:42:38 AM com.fincad.vcr.qa.support.WebDriverFactory createWebDriver

INFO: Web driver is created successfully

1562172170219   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 56792

1562172170243   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on webcompat@mozilla.org version 4.0.0

1562172170249   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on screenshots@mozilla.org version 37.1.0

1562172170253   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on fxmonitor@mozilla.org version 3.0

1562172170254   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on formautofill@mozilla.org version 1.0

[Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 21788, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 21788, Chrome_Chi[Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 6644, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 6644, Chrome_ChildThread] WAR[Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 17844, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Child 17844, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe er[Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1560988628/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341

[Chi###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x1F0099,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Closed channel: cannot send/recv
```

I googled and people mentioned it's due to outdated FF driver, so I upgraded, but it didn't do any good (same errors appear). And in IE it's like Chrome: no error or warning msg at all.

My drivers are these:
Selenium WebDriver: 3.14.0 (32-bit)
geckodriver 0.24.0 (32-bit)
chromedriver 74.0.3729.6 (32-bit)
IEDriverServer 3.8.0 (32-bit)

And my browsers:
Chrome browser: 75.0.3770.100
FF browser: 67.0.4 
IE browser: 11.557.17763

This is how I create my drivers:

```
private static void createFirefoxDriver() {
    setCapability("firefox");
    GeckoDriverService.Builder builder = new GeckoDriverService.Builder();
    GeckoDriverService service = builder.build();
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(capabilities);
    // Read the default firefox profile
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile.getProfile("default");
    // Disable the web page from asking if really want to leave
    myProfile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
    options.setProfile(myProfile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
}

private static void createChromeDriver() {
    setCapability("chrome");
    ChromeDriverService.Builder builder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder();
    ChromeDriverService service = builder.build();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.merge(capabilities);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
}
```

This is how I load the URL (local webdriver):

```
private static void createLocalWebDriver() {
    String browser = ConfigParser.getBrowser();
    LOGGER.info("Target Browser: " + browser);

    switch (browser) {
        case "firefox":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ConfigParser.getGeckoDriver());
            System.out.println("GeckoDriver on: " + ConfigParser.getGeckoDriver());
            createFirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ConfigParser.getChromeDriver());
            System.out.println("ChromeDriver on: " + ConfigParser.getChromeDriver());
            createChromeDriver();
            break;
        case "ie":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ConfigParser.getIEDriverServer());
            System.out.println("IEDriver on: " + ConfigParser.getIEDriverServer());
            createIEDriver();
            break;
        default:
            LOGGER.warning("Unsupported Browser: " + browser);
            break;
    }
}
private static void createFirefoxDriver() {`enter code here`
    setCapability("firefox");
    GeckoDriverService.Builder builder = new GeckoDriverService.Builder();
    GeckoDriverService service = builder.build();
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(capabilities);
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile.getProfile("default");
    myProfile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
    options.setProfile(myProfile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
}

private static void createChromeDriver() {
    setCapability("chrome");
    ChromeDriverService.Builder builder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder();
    ChromeDriverService service = builder.build();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.merge(capabilities);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
}

private static void createIEDriver() {
    setCapability("ie");
    InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder builder = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder();
    InternetExplorerDriverService service = builder.build();
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions(capabilities);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
    CommonJS.executeScript(driver, "window.localStorage.clear();");
    CommonJS.executeScript(driver, "window.sessionStorage.clear();");
}

private static void setCapability(String browser) {
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, true);
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, ConfigParser.getAppUrl());
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    }
}
```

Sorry for all the code, but I'm sure I'll be asked about those details, hence my putting there.
Long story short:

- This only happens with HTTPS URL's
- Non HTTPS URL's work just fine
- It's not an SSL certificate issue otherwise I would have seen it on the screen "This connection is untrusted".

Comment: can you try using chrome driver version 75. link : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.90/

Comment: OK, hang on, will do right away, I'll reply back in an hour or so once I manage to try it.

Comment: No dice, same behavior.
BUT, I was able to fix the problem (it was at page load), so thanks anyway!!

Comment: you can add that and mark it as Answer. It might help someone else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a problem at page load code. Found a section that was explicitly expecting HTTP only, thus refusing to load any HTTPS URL.

Comment: Care to share which piece of code that was? Might be helpful to people looking for similar issue.

Comment: Damn, don't really have it anymore!